# SQL Conditional Join if Variable is Not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, spatial

I have some variable set that could look something like this:

```
SET @ItemID1 = 3
SET @ItemID2 = 26
SET @ItemID3 = NULL
SET @ItemRadius1 = 5000
SET @ItemRadius2 = 5000
SET @ItemRadius3 = NULL
```

The ItemID is a lookup field and the radius is distance in meters. eg The query should return all Assets within 5000 meters of items with the ID of @ItemID1.

My query is currently joining on if the distance between the "Geo" field (which is a geography type) is less than whatever the radius is entetered.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AssetID,
    a.Name
    FROM Asset a
     JOIN Item i1 ON ((a.Geo.STDistance(i1.Geo) < @ItemRadius1) AND i1.TypeID = @ItemID1)
     JOIN Item i2 ON ((a.Geo.STDistance(i2.Geo) < @ItemRadius2) AND i2.TypeID = @ItemID2)
     JOIN Item i3 ON ((a.Geo.STDistance(i3.Geo) < @ItemRadius3) AND i3.TypeID = @ItemID3)
```

My issue is that this is being set up as a procedure and the declared variables may be null. If they are my query will return no results. Is there a way to run the condition only if `@ItemID3 IS NOT NULL AND @ItemRadius3 IS NOT NULL`. I have tried selecting my results into a declared table then running the join on that declared table but my results were not filtering correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: try tihs 
`...
JOIN Item i3 ON
(@ItemRadius3 is null  or ((a.Geo.STDistance(i3.Geo) < @ItemRadius3) )) and (@ItemID3 is null or  i3.TypeID = @ItemID3 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Asset a
WHERE (@ItemID1 IS NULL OR ItemRadius1 IS NULL OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Item i1 
              WHERE a.Geo.STDistance(i1.Geo) < @ItemRadius1 AND i1.TypeID = @ItemID1)
      ) AND
      (@ItemID2 IS NULL OR ItemRadius2 IS NULL OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Item i2
              WHERE a.Geo.STDistance(i2.Geo) < @ItemRadius2 AND i2.TypeID = @ItemID1)
      ) AND
      (@ItemID3 IS NULL OR ItemRadius3 IS NULL OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Item i3
              WHERE a.Geo.STDistance(i3.Geo) < @ItemRadius3 AND i3.TypeID = @ItemID1)
      ) ;
```

At the very least, this eliminates the overhead for the `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: This looks to be filtering correctly on the NULL values, thanks